# How to make OPACITY only on one Item in CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

Problem: After I enter opacity:0.5(or whatever) It applies on all objects that is in header. How can I solve it? Entering opacity:1 in header h1,h2 does not help.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/unyfmf3d/

Here is the css code:

```
body {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    color: black;
}

.header {
    opacity:0.2;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:150px;
    background: white;
}

#header h1 {
    opacity:1;
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    color: #444;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    font-size: 51px;
    line-height:20px;
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#header h2 {
    opacity:1;
    font-family: Gill Sans, Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `opacity` makes the whole div (with content) more transparent.

If you want to only make the background transparent, you can do this:

```
.header {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: white; /*Obligatory fallback color, if the browser doesn't support rgba*/
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

The rgba means Red, Green, Blue, Alpha, and therefore you will need to write the color as RGB-format, whit the alpha being your opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is inherited by children. You could remove the opacity and instead use `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2)` which should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
.header {
   margin:0px auto;
   width:700px;
   height:150px;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to make the background colour transparent use `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);` and remove `opacity:0.2`. The opacity code will affect the entire block.

RGBA stands for Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (or transparency).

JS Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/z0xmfsry/1/

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: One more question. What if I would like to do image background would it look like `background-image(url....)` and then `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);` would the Image become transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible, as the `opacity` setting on the header will *affect* all children, even though technically they are already at `1.0`.

I would use transparency on the header's background, like so;

```
.header {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:700px;
    height:150px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Comment: One more question. What if I would like to do image background would it look like `background-image(url....)` and then `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);` would the Image become transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Because of inheritance, you need to take the `h` elements out of the flow, that is out of the `#header` div to make those `h` elements overlap the div:

https://jsfiddle.net/unyfmf3d/3/

Then you can adjust their position by `top` property.

Here's a nice explanation of this issue:

https://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/